# Clarification regarding Oracle SQL date-syntax(fm )?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm studying SQL and I see this notation to display the date :

```
SELECT last_name, TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'fmDD Month YYYY') AS HIREDATE FROM employees
```

What is the meaning of the prefix of `fm` ? thanks

Comment: You mean [what does the documentation say](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#sthref451)? "The FM modifier suppresses the above padding in the return value of the TO_CHAR function"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fm` prefix specifies that you don't want to get leading characters ([see docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF30003)).  By default, the `to_char` function will produce a fixed width string (this goes back to when Oracle was created and people wanted to generate text based reports that would be sent to a printer with a fixed width font so it was useful for everything to have the same number of characters).

For example, the format mask `Month` spells out the month.  By default, that will be space padded out to the length of the longest month name (September in English so 9 characters).  The `fm` prefix gets rid of those spaces.  It also gets rid of the leading 0 on the day if it's prior to the 10th of the month.  If you were generating a text report to a printer, this would be painful because your columns don't line up any more.  In modern tools, it just removes annoying extraneous characters.